# Double popping to close alert and get the previous rote

Tags: flutter

I've found that I'm using double `Navigator.pop` to close alert and poping the current route.
Is it ok or there is other way to do it?

```
Alert( // rflutter_alert package
  context: context,
  desc: "Flutter is awesome.",
  closeFunction: () {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
).show();
```

Comment: If you want to close the alert and go back to previous route, I think there is no problem with this. You could use `popUntil` with a counter or with a named route, but it basically does the same. Or use `Navigator.of(context) ..pop() ..pop();`.